# Loading new file into DistributedCache

Tags: hadoop

I have one teoretical case. I have one file that I load into DistributedCache. Then I run my mapreduce program.

After completion of the job, I want to update my file.
DistributedCache will automaticli download new version of the file, when I run my program with the same parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when a job is resubmitted the distributed cache file should also get updated. 
After a job is submitted with a distributed cache file ( e.g. using -file option), the task tracker copies the file to its local disk. This file will be now available to the mapper.
Hence when a job is resubmitted, the task tracker should copy the file again to the local disk. So When it does that it will get the updated file to Task Tracker's local file system.

Also note that task tracker maintains a reference count for each file in cache. After job is completed and count becomes zero,the file will be eligible for deletion (after it exceeds local.cache.size).